# Avoid the warning "What does the phrase "Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph", while keeping the line space as using \\[<space>]

Tags: line-spacing, warnings, vertical-spacing, badness

There is plenty of advice to avoid line break by `\\` and use an empty line for going to the next line. My problem is that the template I am using is full of warnings of

> Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph

and there is no way but to stick to the template. The warnings does bother me and I don't want to trick a turn off the warning. So I tried the solutions in the below code to 1. avoid the warning, and 2. get EXACTLY the SAME output as the template. I don't have the reputation to comment; so, thanks to `jlab` for his advice, the question is revised. As seen, none of the solutions result in the SAME vertical spacing between lines, as depicted below.

[image: difference between vertical spacing of two similar code]

How could I solve it?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[
paperwidth=3.6in,
paperheight=.7in,
margin=.1in,
centering]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}{.48\linewidth}
    This is the first line.\\[-.45cm]
    \hrule height 1pt
    \vspace{.5mm}
    \hrule height 2.5pt
    \vspace{1.5mm}
    This is the second line.
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{.48\linewidth}
    This is the first line.

    \vspace*{-\parskip+\baselineskip-.45cm}
    \hrule height 1pt
    \vspace{.5mm}
    \hrule height 2.5pt
    \vspace{1.5mm}
    This is the second line.
  \end{minipage}

  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}{.48\linewidth}
    This is the first line.\\[-.45cm]
    \hrule height 1pt
    \vspace{.5mm}
    \hrule height 2.5pt
    \vspace{1.5mm}
    This is the second line.
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{.48\linewidth}
    This is the first line.

    \par\vspace*{\baselineskip}\vspace*{-.45cm}
    \hrule height 1pt
    \vspace{.5mm}
    \hrule height 2.5pt
    \vspace{1.5mm}
    This is the second line.
  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
Thanks to `wipet` for explaining the background of what `LaTeX` does when faces `\\` that excited me to go deeper into `LaTeX`. I'm afraid the offered solution didn't make the same output as `\\` does. As it can be seen, the `hrule`s in the adjacent `minipage`s are not at the same level. It seems that, in practice, the vertical spacing forced by `\\` is not EXACTLY the SAME as `line-spacing`; but, I don't know how to calculate/consider this difference. Here is the `MWE`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[
paperwidth=3.6in,
paperheight=.7in,
margin=.1in,
centering]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}{.48\linewidth}
    This is the first line.\\[-.45cm]
    \hrule height 1pt
    \vspace{.5mm}
    \hrule height 2.5pt
    \vspace{1.5mm}
    This is the second line.
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{.48\linewidth}
    This is the first line.
    
    \vspace{\dimexpr-\parskip+\baselineskip-.45cm}
    \hrule height 1pt
    \vspace{.5mm}
    \hrule height 2.5pt
    \vspace{1.5mm}
    This is the second line.
  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To compute the sum `-\parskip+\baselineskip-.45cm` either use the `calc` package or the `\dimexpr` command: `\dimexpr -\parskip+\baselineskip-.45cm \relax`

Comment: never use `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph, `\hrule` (which is not a latex command) ends the current paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in plain TeX:

```
text of the first paragraph\nobreak\hfil\break\par

next paragraph
\bye
```

You can see Underfull \hbox mesage and empty line is inserted after the first paragraph. Why? The `\par` command inserts `\parfillskip` glue followed by final break. But the glue is discardable item, so it is removed after the first `\break` and you have `\break\break`. TeX tries to create this empty line with given width `\hsize`, but there is no stretchable glue here. So, you have Underfull `\hbox`.

Now, what happens from your LaTeX point of view: The `\\[-.45cm]` expands (roughly speaking) to `\vadjust{\vskip-.45cm}\nobreak\hfil\break` The following `\hrule` TeX primitive inserts `\par` to the input queue and it is ready to be read again. So, you have `\vadjust{\vskip-.45cm}\nobreak\hfil\break\par\hrule`. Note, that there is the same sequence like in the previous example: `\nobreak\hfil\break\par`. This causes the Underfull message.

I don't know what is your intend. You create the empty line and then you remove the space where is this line using negative vertical space in `\vadjust`. It seems that it is over-complicated.

**Edit** The difference (you are asking about) can be visible if your first line has non zero depth, i.e. replace the text `the first line` by `the first gline` (for example) at four places. And do correct your bad usage of `\vspace{-\parskip+\baselineskip-.45cm}` by  `\vspace{\dimexpr-\parskip+\baselineskip-.45cm}`. At the left column, you are at the bottom of an empty box when you start the vertical spaces dancing. At the right column, you compensate empty line by adding `\baselineskip` but you are at the bottom of the non-empty line with nonzero depth. So, you are at lower place than in the left column (difference is the nonzero depth).

Comment: As I understand, Abbas Shams want to reproduce exactly the output of the left minipages in the right minipages without using `\\`, in order to suppress warnings.

Comment: Thanks to `jlab`, to be more precise, I want to suppress the warnings in the way that  reproduce exactly the output of the left minipages in the right minipages.

Comment: @AbbasShams Use `\par\null\vskip-.45cm` instead `\vspace{\dimexpr-\parskip+\baselineskip-.45cm}` just before the first `\hrule`. The `\null` macro inserts the empty box as in the left column. Then the `\vskip-.45cm` starts from the bottom of the empty box (similarly like in the left column).

Comment: Thank you `wipe`. `\par\null\vskip-.45cm` worked for me and it is the exact replacement for `\\[-.45cm]`. For the sake of completeness, please add this advice as a new edition to your answer.